# How to declare a static variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype-oriented

In the following code, I would like to have a counter to keep track of the number of Person objects created. This code is not doing so, how would I accomplish that?

```
function Person(){
    this.name = "Peter";
    this.counter = this.counter + 1;
    alert(this.counter);
}

Person.prototype.counter = 0;

var p1 = new Person;
var p2 = new Person;
```

Comment: Can somebody explain how this actually works.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

```
function Person(){
    this.name = "Peter";
    Person.counter++;
    alert(Person.counter);
}

Person.counter = 0;

var p1 = new Person();
var p2 = new Person();
```

Make the "static" variable a property of the `Person` function, rather than the `prototype`, and use `Person` instead of `this` inside the constructor.

This is possible because JavaScript functions are first-class (i.e. they are objects), so can have properties of their own.

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/RhXPC/) of the above code.

Comment: 3rd answer, but the most complete/correct.

Comment: If I have counter inside `Person`, then how can I obtain it from it's intance, like `p1?`

Comment: @Dims you can get it from a reference to the constructor: `p1.constructor.counter`

Comment: I'd like to add it's not necessary to use `Person.counter`, `Person.prototype.counter` would works too. the point is you cannot use `this.counter` (or more specifically, *set* it)

Answer (score 12):

You can also make your counter variable "private", declaring it as local to a closure.
It's the best way to have something similar to private - static variables:

```
var Person = (function() {

    var counter = 0;

    return function() {
        counter++;
        this.name = "Peter";
        alert(counter);
    };
})();


var p1 = new Person();
var p2 = new Person();
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/patodiblasi/67wucsqx/

Answer (score 6):

There are no static properties. If you want you can store data on the `Person` function.

```
function Person(){
    this.name = "Peter";
    Person.counter++;
    alert(Person.counter);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For a static you can assign a property to the function object itself;

```
Person.counter = 0;
```

And within the constructor increment with;

```
Person.counter += 1;
```

You can also check-if-undefined and create `Person.counter` within the constructor

```
function Person(){
   if (typeof Person.counter === 'undefined')
      Person.counter = 0;
   else
      Person.counter += 1;
   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing like static class variables/properties in js. The simplest approach is just use the "class" function as a namespace for static variables.

It means, just access in Person.count directly.

You can use closures as well, but actually in 90% cases it will be overkill.
In modern browsers you also can redefine getter/setter function to wrap usage of Person.count and other "static" variables.

This snippet demonstrates the idea:

```
    function borrow(obj, borrowobj, fname) {
    obj.__defineGetter__(fname, function() {
         return borrowobj[fname]   
    })  

    obj.__defineSetter__(fname, function(val) {
             borrowobj[fname] = val      
    })
}

function Person() {
    borrow(this, Person, "count");
    this.count++
}

Person.count = 0;

new Person();
new Person();
var p = new Person();
alert(p.count);
```