# Call recursive function and keep variable local

Tags: javascript, loops, recursion

I try to make a recursive function but one important variabel (others too) is replace by recursive call before `for(){}` loop. I want the variable local (private, only for the current function and not overrided by recursive call)... I've tried a lot of thing... any idea ?

```
function parseChilds( elements, desired, array ){

        if( !isArray(elements) ){

            if( elements instanceof NodeList ){

                elements = objectToArray(elements);

            }
            else {

                elements = [elements];

            };

        };

        for( var el = 0; el < elements.length; el++ ){

            console.log("EL", elements[el], desired);
            if( elements[el].tagName.toLowerCase() === desired.tag[0] && desired.tag.length === 1 ){

                array.push(elements[el]);

            };

            if( elements[el].nodeType === 1 ){

                var childrens = elements[el].children;

                if( childrens.length > 0 && desired.tag.length > 1 ){

                    desired.tag = arrayRemoveFirst(desired.tag);

                    for( var child = 0; child < childrens.length; child++  ){

                        if( childrens[child].nodeType === 1 ){

                            parseChilds(childrens[child], desired, array);

                        };

                    };

                };

            };

        };
};
```

Thx, J.

**Edit :** The `desired.tag` is overrided by the recursive call before the el = 1 in for loop...

Comment: maybe you could tell us WHICH variable, so that we don't have to search the code for it ;)

Comment: Your question is not clear.  `desired` is passed to your recursive call.  You can make it anything you want in the recursive call by passing whatever you want to pass in it's place.

Comment: @Asped
I try:
var el = 0;
while(elements[el]){
...
...
el++;
};

But that do not change anything.

Comment: @jfriend00
The desired contain a tag list (array), each time i call the function, i remove the first element of this array and pass it to the recursive function, but when the for loop continue to 1, the desired.tag is already empty...

Answer (score 0):

Although I  do not really get what you try to do with your code,as long as  you want to have a "local, private" variable, which "stays" the same in all the function calls and you can change it independetnly of the recursion, I think you need a "static" variable. look into this post, it could help you:

[How to declare a static variable in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7307243/how-to-declare-a-static-variable-in-javascript)

Comment: The first time i call the function, it look like: parseChilds(elements, desired, array); elements contain two header (NodeList), desired contain tag, desired.tag is an array => "h1", "span", "b". Every time i call the parseChilds Fn, I remove the first of desired.tag, but I want to remove it only on the last instance of desired.tag, I dont want to affect/override ancestor desired.tag.
Am I clear ?